# How to create a calculated field which uses multiple row data in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have this kind of data :

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| ID      | City       |    District     |  Amount  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 121    | Delhi       |    D1           |  1000$   |
| 122    | Delhi       |    D2           |  1200$   |
| 123    | Moscow      |    M1           |  1125$   |
| 124    | Delhi       |    D3           |  7600$   |
| 125    | Shanghai    |    S1           |  3400$   |
| 126    | Shanghai    |    S2           |  3100$   |
| 127    | Moscow      |    M2           |  9900$   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to create a table calculation which basically check if some `District` are in some `City`.

```
// Calculated field

IF [city] = 'Delhi'
AND [District] = 'D1'
AND [District] = 'D2'
THEN "Category 1"

ELSE IF [city] = 'Moscow'
AND [District] = 'M1'
AND [District] = 'M3'
THEN "Category 2"
END
```

I know this calculated field is wrong. I am not able to find a workaround to create the same logic as present in the (wrong) calculated field here. What is the right way to create this calculated field ?

Comment: Can you add the expected output of the calculated field from your data above? For example for Dehli, would it be summing D1 and D2 to get $2200?

Comment: @DanielSims Yes I can do that. But main thing I want to know is how can I check the conditions in `IF` statement ?  For ease I am going to edit the question.

Comment: I've edited question with table which would show potential outputs of your calculation. Please change it accordingly. This will help when trying to understand the logic of your calculation and desired results.

Comment: Looks like the edit needs to be peer reviewed so it'll take some time. Take a look when it shows up though. In the meantime, I've attempted an answer based on what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: And it looks like the edit was rejected for some reason. In your example data above, if you placed a column called "Calculation" to the right, would it look like this?: ID 121 and 122 = Category 1. Everything else null. If you can please create a table which would show the expected output for each row, it would be good.

Comment: @DanielSims yes. If I placed a column `Calculation` then `ID 121` and `ID122` should have `Category 1` and everything else is null. There is no `M3` district in `Moscow` thats why it is null for `Moscow` .

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, unfortunately. Tableau Calculated Fields typically operate on their own row, there are a few exceptions in table calcs: previous() will look at the row before, and window_xxx() functions can count or sum the number of rows. What is being asked here is essentially to search all rows for a certain pair of values (imagine if the dataset was 1 billion rows, Moscow M1 was ID 1 and Moscow M3 was ID 1,000,000,000.) What I might suggest is __Tableau Prep__ for reshaping the data prior to its arrival into Tableau Desktop. I wish I had better news.

Comment: @DanielSims I was suspecting the same thing but I had to be sure. Thanks for the clarification.